# Where did the Shopify webhook for order update go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

I need to subscribe to the order update Shopify webhook. The thing is, is I can't find it! They have changed the way the `shopify_app.rb` config file is structured. So this is the way it looks now:

```
config.scope = "read_shipping, write_shipping, read_products, write_products, 
              read_fulfillments, write_fulfillments, read_orders, write_orders, read_themes, write_themes, orders/updated"
```

Looking at the Shopify docs it doesn't look like the order update hook exists anymore. [According to their own docs](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth/scopes)

But there is this old doc that does contain the order update hook: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/events/webhook

I put that style into my `config.scope` line but I got this when I try and install: https://nimb.ws/JH267z

Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm just trying sh*t now.. I tried `update_orders` and that didn't work: https://nimb.ws/Yun5Us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope has nothing to do with Webhook subscriptions. If you subscribe to a webhook like orders/update, then you receive orders at your designated end point when the update occurs.

Scope is more of an authorization tool, for API access to endpoints at Shopify. No matter what you do with scope, it will not add a webhook subscription for you. For that, you call the Webhook endpoint and add the webhook you need.

Comment: ehh you're right Dave.. was getting confused as usual. Only been doing Shopify apps for 3 years now, you'd think I'd have it down..

Comment: I have been doing them for a lot longer and I still get burned by things like that too. It is a lot to juggle at once, never mind extending the juggle over 10 years of evolving systems.